# Creating a new marker on a map

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, angular.js

Is this code good practice? What kind of design pattern should I use for this specific situation?

The following function creates a new marker on a map. It sets a new image for it, *except when the marker references the user location*.

```
$scope.addMarker = function (lat, lng, isUserLocation) {

    if (typeof(isUserLocation) === undefined || isUserLocation === false) 
        var icon = "img/marker-map.png";

    $scope.markers.push({
        latitude: parseFloat(lat),
        longitude: parseFloat(lng),
        icon: icon
    });
}
```

Maybe just `(!isUserLocation)` is more readable - is it error prone?

Here's a call to the function to create the "user location" marker:

```
$scope.addMarker(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, true);
```

If someone reads that, he/she wouldn't be able to say what that `true` is for and would have to look for the `addMarker()` function, for example. But maybe that's no big deal or is it?

Here's the function that creates all other markers:

```
$scope.populateMarkers = function(locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        $scope.addMarker(locations[i].Latitude, locations[i].Longitude);
    }
}
```

This is the HTML / Angular directives that references the markers inside the map:

```
  <markers>
    <marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker" icon="marker.icon">
    </marker>
  </markers>
```

It works, but since I'm very new to AngularJS and I also thought about many different ways to do just that, I'd like to know how people would do it and/or whether there is a recommended design pattern for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question,

I haven't found an obvious best way to do this.

For sure, sending `true` as a parameter should always be avoided, I'd rather see

```
var IS_USER_LOCATION = true;
$scope.addMarker(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, IS_USER_LOCATION);
```

though probably I would create 2 functions, 1 called `addMarker` and 1 called `addUserMarker`.

Finally, it amused me that the first 2 parameters in both calls are properties of the same object, so why not just ask for a coordinates object ?

```
$scope.addMarker = function ( coordinates ) {
    $scope.markers.push({
        latitude: parseFloat(coordinates.latitude),
        longitude: parseFloat(coordinates.longitude),
        icon: "img/marker-map.png";
    });
}

$scope.addUserMarker = function ( coordinates ) {
    $scope.markers.push({
        latitude: parseFloat(coordinates.latitude),
        longitude: parseFloat(coordinates.longitude),
    });
}

$scope.addUserMarker(position);

$scope.populateMarkers = function(locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        $scope.addMarker(locations[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed

```
if (!isUserLocation)
```

is probably preferable to the more verbose

```
if (typeof(isUserLocation) === undefined || isUserLocation === false)
```

In that case, `isUserLocation` is a function argument, so using it won't throw any error (in contrast to a *variable*) and hence there is no need for `typeof`. Also note that `null === false` evaluates to `false`, so the two expressions are different, strictly speaking.